# How to pass parameter to stored procudere from DBRead function (CPLEX 12.6.1.0)?

Tags: sql-server, cplex

Let's assume I have next stored procedure "myprocedure":

```
USE [MYDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[myprocedure]
(     
  @myparam as int
)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT *

  from bigtable

  where myfield = @myparam
)
```

In CPLEX I have data file "mydata.dat", where I want to execute this procedure as parameterized query with specific parameter, which is also defined in this file:

```
myparam = 1;

DBConnection db(*connection details*);

Mydata from DBRead(db, "SELECT * FROM myprocedure(?)")(myparam);
```

If you try to run this project, you will get the error:

> Database error (state=42000 code=0) Syntax error or access violation,
> near "Mydata"

So my question is:
****Is there a way to execute this parameterized query in IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.6.1.0?****

Comment: BTW that's an Inline Table-Valued Function, not a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you for correction

Comment: FWIW, you would call that the same way you would call `select * from sometable where somecol = ?`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Yes, that's how it is implemented now. It'd like to store frequently used functions (especially long ones) on server's side

Answer (score -3):

In 12.6 we could call stored procedures with DBRead, DBUpdate and  DBExecute : I recommend the technote https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/125517 where we can read

Question

> How can I call a stored procedure in OPL?

Answer

> If your stored procedure has parameters, you can call it with DBRead
> to initialize data:
>
> aSet from DBRead(db,"BEGIN opl_proc_output(:1); END;");
>
> To save data, use DBUpdate:
>
> aSet to DBUpdate(db,"BEGIN opl_proc_input(:1); END;");
>
> If a stored procedure has no parameters, you can call it with
> DBExecute:
>
> DBExecute(db,"BEGIN opl_proc_noparam; END;");

Comment: Thanks for response, but this solution is not working at all :(